# data overwrite in pdf file when data insert using java

Tags: java, file, pdf, insert, record

```
if(ae.getSource() == b1)  // click on button
{
    **String path = "E:\\new pdffolder\\mypdf.pdf"; // file path and name
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream(path,true));
    doc.open();**        
    PdfPTable tb1 = new PdfPTable(10);  
    doc.add(new Paragraph("client project pdf"));
    tb1.addCell("ClientName"); //static data
    tb1.addCell("ProjectName"); //static data
    tb1.addCell("ClientEmail");//static data
    tb1.addCell("Clientpasword");//static data
    tb1.addCell("ProjectAmount");//static data
    tb1.addCell("TaxAmount");//static data
    tb1.addCell("TotalAmount");//static data
    tb1.addCell("Startdate");//static data
    tb1.addCell("EndDate");//static data
    tb1.addCell("description");//static data
    *tb1.addCell(client_name); // variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell( Project_name);// variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(client_email);// variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(password);   // variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(String.valueOf( project_amount)); // variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(String.valueOf(tax_amount)); // variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(String.valueOf(total_amount));// variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(start_date);// variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(end_date);// variable name that read data frm txt feild
    tb1.addCell(project_description);// variable name that read data frm txt feild
    doc.add(tb1);* 
 }
 doc.close();
```

> this is code in which i have problem i have a problem that only one and single record is storred in pdf file may be overwrite please if i need a help if pure java developer is here ..

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please simplify the code you have problems with. It is harder to isolate the problem when looking for an answer if there is more code than necessary to demonstrate the problem. For example, does the problem persist if you remove most of the `tb1.addCell()` calls? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more inspiration.

Comment: i want to add the record in pdf file and data is overwrite using java...simple proble is this.

Comment: My friend, I don’t know the answer, I just wanted to give you tips on how to increase your chances of getting an answer. The simpler a question looks, the higher probability of getting an answer.

Comment: sir will you give me your gmail id i have one more problem may be you can help me on that probllem..?

Comment: *"only one and single record is storred in pdf file"* - you only add a single record to the table in your code, so no wonder there is only one in the result pdf.

Comment: i want to enter multiple records means cell will create in run time..just like in database